# Need to determine a matrix to align two triangles

Tags: c++, rotation, directx-9

I need to determine a matrix representing the transform required to align two known-to-be-congruent triangles in 3D.  I've previously tried asking about taking [a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132720/finding-rotation-between-two-congruent-triangles) but I've been hitting a lot of snags with it so I'm now looking at trying different ideas.

Is anyone able to direct me to how I can just create a matrix to represent the translation and rotation required to move a triangle (`DEF`) into the same position and orientation as another (`ABC`) where `A` is at the origin?

Comment: by "known-to-be-congruent" you mean have the same internal angels ?

Comment: @Roee, Yes.  The two triangles can be assumed to be identical save some translation and rotation.  I've been told there's no need to worry about scaling.  Internal angles and side lengths should be equal between the two triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. think of a "basic" triangle. XYZ when X = (0,0,0), Y = (1,0,0) and Z where ever, depending on the angles.
2nd. for each triangle find the way to move it to this "basic".
for DEF it's, move D to A using basic move action. rotate around z until E is in xz plan, rotate around x until F is in xy plan in the x+ side.
if that's clear then you know how to create a matrix to move each triangle to the same basic triangle.
now.. if you take an Identify matrix, and for every action you do on (2nd) on the right side of the matrix you will do the opposite action on the left of Identify matrix, you will end up with a matrix to move from the basic triangle to your triangle.

I hope it make seance, explaining in English is a bit difficult to me...

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to my mind (and this may be neither the simplest nor the most efficient way to do things) is to begin by computing the [circumcenters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcenter) of your triangles. The unique line passing through them can then be used to build the [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix) that will let you drag one triangle onto the other (possibly making them intersect).

Since you have the triangles, you can also compute the equations of the respective planes that contain them, the angle between those planes, and therefore also the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) that you need to apply so that both triangles end up in the same plane. Finally, you need to apply one final rotation to match your triangles that now lie in the same plane.